# Missing metrics in CloudWatch/Grafana

Tags: elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch, grafana

I'm setting up some dashboards in Grafana using data from AWS CloudWatch for an EB application.

It works fine for getting EnvironmentHealth, however for anything else I get "No data point".

I have tried selecting **ApplicationRequestsTotal** **ApplicationRequests2xx** **CPUIdle** Different latencies, etc

On [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/aeb-metricscollected.html) I don't see any different recommendation for other metric types.

**Works:**
us-east-1 → AWS/ElasticBeanstalk → EnvironmentHealth → Stats → Maximum

**Don't work:**
us-east-1 → AWS/ElasticBeanstalk → ApplicationRequestsTotal → Stats → Maximum

I have also changed from Maximum to Average, Minimum, etc.

Even going to AWS CloudWatch to create dashboard I can only see the EnvironmentHealth metric when I select per Environment.

Do I have to enable anything on CloudWatch to allow other metrics?

Comment: I recommend you to check Prometheus, it's got a great metrics exporter for CloudWatch, will make your life so much easier, check out this project: https://github.com/shelleg/prometheus-stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Elastic Beanstalk, go to your env, configuration, monitoring and choose the metrics that you want to see.

You should also be aware that this might induce additional charges to your aws account.

Some stats are also available as part of ELB metrics in CloudWatch.